# host disable php mail function

Tags: php, wordpress

My host has disabled mail function , as he has said for security reasons . But my wordpress website needs  it; I have access to cpanel .
DO anyone has an idea how to deal with that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use an external mail provider, like Amazon SES or Sendgrid. Trying to bypass your host's security restrictions is a good way to get shut off; their infrastructure, their rules.

Answer (score 1):

As you have rightly indicated in your question "it was disabled for security reasons." Web Hosters have the right to disable accounts when the account's activity goes against its usage policies.

When the mail is used for spam then it will be disabled. You may need to disable some plugins that makes use of the email service. An example is to disable receiving of email notification when a user comments on a post.

Also, you can email your web hosters and enquire on specific things to do in order curb the "security issue".